# gvim remove menu and toolbar, but keep original geometry

Tags: vimrc, gvim, bash

I start gvim with this entry in .bashrc
`alias G='gvim -fg white -bg black -geom 80x45 '`
and have in .vimrc
`set guioptions=aeik`

which works as expected and gives me a gvim that looks like vim in a tty, except that the 3 lines lost by removing the menu and toolbar are gone, and the remaining geometry is 80x42.

Making the initial geometry 80x48 to compensate does not work as this asks for a window taller than the screen, and apparently is just ignored. How can I get rid of the menu and toolbar and also maximize the window height?

Comment: Try setting the guioptions in gvimrc instead (though I don’t actually know if that’s relevant to your problem)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  That won't help, .gvimrc is processed after .vimrc, and the problem is the command line is processed first, setting the geometry, and while the guioptions can reduce that geometry, there seems to be no option that preserves the original geometry.

Comment: But eliminating the menu/toolbar are usually done in gvimrc precisely because some things (guioptions) are *reset* **when the GUI starts**! This happens *before* processing the gvimrc...

Comment: No matter which vim you start, it processes the command line first, then .vimrc, then .gvimrc if it exists. :h startup gives the full sequence of events.

Comment: The problem lies in :set lines=45. Turns out you can set my gvim to any number of lines less than 42, but over 41 has no effect

Comment: That’s not entirely correct re: startup order, and I was going based on `:h startup`—terminal vims, for example, do not source gvimrc even if it exists. And before a gvimrc is sourced by a gvim, certain options are forcibly reset to their defaults *even if overriden in a vimrc*.

Comment: If I start vim in a terminal it will not process .gvimrc at all. But if I start gvim, it processes both .vimrc and .gvimrc, if they are available.  Regardless, as I understand the situation now, the problem is that lubuntu's compilation of gvim is limited to 41 lines (the height that exactly fits the height of the screen). I guess if I want it different, I'll have to compile from source, which probably means I'll put up with it as it is. Thanks for your help.